# Как подставить изображение в зависимости от состояния кнопки?

Tags: qt, qt5, qml

Всем привет! 
Как поставить изображение на кнопку - я сделал так:

```
Button {
    id: btn
    width: 250
    height: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "A button"
    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Image {
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "btn_state.png"
        }
      }
    }
```

Я только не знаю как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изображение менялось и вновь восстанавливалось на исходное изображение. 
Я пробовал пробросить **MouseArea**, но тогда я не могу использовать стили для замены изображения. Весь день прокопался с этим, и теперь прошу вашей помощи.

**Это стандартная кнопка (btn_state)**
[image: Эта стандартная кнопка]

**Это нажатая кнопка (btn_pressed)**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто, в стиле доступен control, к которому применяется стиль. Остаётся только использовать `pressed` свойство оного:

```
style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Image {
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: control.pressed ? "btn_pressed.png" :
                 (control.hovered ? "btn_hovered.png" : "btn_state.png") 
        }
      }
```

Comment: Отлично! Работает. Спасибо Вам большое

Я так понял, что анимацию сюда не прикрутить? 
Просто суть этой кнопки такова: есть стандартная кнопка: btn_state, при наведении кнопка (btn_hovered) плавно перерисовывается в другое изображение, при нажатии меняется, тоже плавно, на совсем другое (btn_pressed)

Comment: Да всё что угодно можно прикрутить, было бы желание. Правда, я не сильно понимаю, как Вы собираетесь плавно анимировать изображения — достаточно просто их смены, чтобы имитировать кнопку. Если ответ Вам подходит, тогда, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой(рядом с ответом)

Comment: Анимация - обычная перерисовка. Разве нельзя?

Comment: @razorqhex, а что Вы собираетесь анимировать? К примеру, анимируя `width` мы плавно меняем значения, скажем, от 0 до 100, что здесь будет меняться? У Вас 3 изображения, между которыми идёт смена — просто меняйте их и всё.

Comment: ну смотрите: есть сталая кнопка. По наведению прорисовывается новое изображение. Когда мышь за зоной кнопки - то наведённая кнопка исчезает, а на её месте стоит та же сталая кнопка. Разве так нельзя?

Comment: @razorqhex, именно так и получится с кодом, что выше, только нужно ещё добавить обработку hover. Т.е. это можно назвать анимацией, да, но в QML, всё-таки, анимация это отдельный модуль, поэтому когда говорят об анимации в QML, то подразумевается плавное интерполирования каких-то значений, а не просто смена изображений.

Comment: Можно анимировать свойство opacity при смене изображений. Но, скорее всего, тогда придется кнопку делать по-другому.

Comment: @ixSci, Я пробовал вот таким методом: я в style: ButtonStyle{}
запихнул MouseArea{} и там onEntered: {onEntered: Image{source: "btn_hovered.png}}

Comment: @razorqhex, исправил ответ — смотрите.

Comment: @ixSci, да! Всё отлично работает. Спасибо Вам большое. Как я могу Вас отблагодарить? Могу хоть пивом? Всё супер. Спасибо :) 

И ещё оде вопрос (чисто технический): почему когда я пишу: control.pressed или color: control.pressed ? "red" : "black" то нету выпадающего списка после точки (control.). Это кака-то старая функция, которая не поддерживается? Или как?

Comment: @razorqhex, Да не надо меня никак благодарить, спасибо :) Почему не работает intellisense — не знаю, всегда нужно смотреть документацию, т.к. не всегда IDE может показать все возможные функции и свойства.

Comment: @ixSci, понял. Спасибо Вам большое за помощь :)

Comment: @pier_nasos спасибо Вам за отзыв и за то что не прошли мимо :)